# Dynamically creating a link to a custom made page with Drupal Module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

So I want my module to make a page first. But the link to the simple page should be user entered.
I`m doing this on Drupal 7.
I made a settings form in the _menu function.

```
   $items['admin/config/content/settings'] = array(
           'title' => 'Setings', 
           'description' => 'A form to change settings',
           'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
           'page arguments' => array('settings_form'), 
           'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
           'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
```

Then I added this:

```
function settings_form($form, &$form_state){
    $form['locationUrl'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t("URL kādu vēlaties?"),
        '#description' => t("Example. about"),
        '#required' => true
    );
    return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

And then i added to the _menu function:

```
$items[variable_get('admin/config/content/settings','locationUrl')] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => '', //page title
    'page callback' => 'DGMap', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
    'access arguments' => array('access simple page'),
);
```

And i add this:

```
function page(){
   return array('#markup' => '<h1>Hello?</h1>');
}
```

I save it all up. Clear cache. And go to settings and save the locationUrl as for example 'about'. And then try /drupal/about it gives me page not found exception.

Could anyone please help me with this? I hope that it is understandable what im trying to make.

Thanks for help.

The end thing i want to make is so that my module could create a page with custom JavaScript in it. If anyone could link me to a tutorial that would be great for this, i would really appreciate that. If there is a way for my module to place custom created JavaScript in the page that would be fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's a good aproach for dynamic routing but you're getting the variable wrong for your second link in `hook_menu()`. In fact you make a route to `YourDrupal/locationUrl` instead of your example `YourDrupal/about`.

Use this for the second menu link (with an extra check on whether or not the setting is being saved):

```
if (!empty($setting = variable_get('locationUrl', ''))) {
    $items[$setting] = array( 
        'title' => '', //page title
        'page callback' => 'page', // use the same name as your pagecallback 
        // 'access arguments' => array('access simple page'),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'), // temporarily use this
    );
}
```

You also might be in need of a check on existing routes. Not sure what happens if the user has saved your form with a `locationUrl` like for example "admin" giving a link to `YourDrupal/admin` which already exists.

Comment: It worked! Only thing I should add is that after doing the configuration save part I had to clear cache again. Thank you very much for help! :) Do you have any idea how could i automate this? So that the cache is cleared after saving.

Comment: `cache_clear_all();` might do that in a submit handler. But then I think you'd have to step away from the automation provided by `system_settings_form($form);` & write the form custom to save your configuration. The **DrupalStackExchange** users can probably give you a better  answer on that :)